# Plugins with element criteria selection does not work for empty or zero values

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

I made a plugin which count the number of users per groups defined by the field `accent` which is a text field and can be **empty** or contain **numbers** from 0 to 12.

```
public function actionCountUsers() {

    // Delete all the entry caches
    craft()->templateCache->deleteCachesByElementType('User');

    // Now find the entry IDs
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('User', array('group' => 'unepMembers', 'limit' => null, 'status' => null, 'localeEnabled' => null));
    $criteria->group = 'unepMembers';
    $criteria->limit = null;
    $criteria->status = null;
    $criteria->localeEnabled = null;

    //
    $totalEntries = $criteria->total();
    UnepPlugin::log($totalEntries.' USERS (no criteria)', LogLevel::Warning);

    //
    $criteria->accent = '';
    $totalEntries = $criteria->total();
    UnepPlugin::log($totalEntries.' USERS with empty accent', LogLevel::Warning);

    //
    $totalUsers = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++) {
        $criteria->accent = $i;
        $totalEntries = $criteria->total();
        MigPlugin::log($totalEntries.' USERS with accent :'.$criteria->accent, LogLevel::Warning);

        $totalUsers = $totalUsers + $totalEntries;
    }
    MigPlugin::log($totalUsers.' USERS with accents', LogLevel::Warning);

}
```

As you can see the result here below there is a problem with a criteria values **empty** or **0** on the `accent` field: they just do not work and count the total number of users.

```
***********************
2015/10/11 07:09:48 [warning] [plugin] 3109 USERS (no criteria)  
2015/10/11 07:09:48 [warning] [plugin] 3109 USERS with empty accent  
2015/10/11 07:14:01 [warning] [plugin] 3109 USERS with accent :0  
2015/10/11 07:09:48 [warning] [plugin] 1849 USERS with accent :1  
2015/10/11 07:09:48 [warning] [plugin] 501 USERS with accent :2  
2015/10/11 07:09:48 [warning] [plugin] 0 USERS with accent :3  
2015/10/11 07:09:48 [warning] [plugin] 72 USERS with accent :4  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 8 USERS with accent :5  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 1 USERS with accent :6  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 0 USERS with accent :7  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 4 USERS with accent :8  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 81 USERS with accent :9  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 232 USERS with accent :10  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 246 USERS with accent :11  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 115 USERS with accent :12  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 0 USERS with accent :13  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 0 USERS with accent :14  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 0 USERS with accent :15  
2015/10/11 07:09:49 [warning] [plugin] 3109 USERS with accents
```

Craft bug or did I miss something in my code?

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```php
$criteria->accent = '';
```

Craft is going to look for users where the `accent` field’s DB cell is an empty string.

Those values are probably `null` though, if they aren’t getting returned.

Try setting your `accent` param to `:empty:` instead of `''`. When you do that, Craft will search for both empty strings *and* `null` values, so you should get the results you’re expecting.

Comment: OK thx now I see the number lines for empty strings and `null` values is correct : `$criteria->accent = ':empty:';`  > 1306 USERS with empty/NULL accent. 
But there is still a strange thing with the value zero : it gives 3109 users, so the total number users.

Comment: Try changing `$criteria->accent = $i;` to `$criteria->accent = (string)$i;`

Comment: Not working. Still give me the total number of users. I tried also to provide it specifically : `$criteria->accent = '0';` but same thing (total number of users = 3109). Really bizarre...